# Django ORM Creates Phantom Alias in SQL Join

Tags: mysql, django, join, django-orm, mysql-error-1054

I am executing the following code (names changed to protect the innocent, so the model structure might seem weird):

```
memberships = 
    models.Membership.objects.filter(
        degree__gt=0.0,
        group=request.user.get_profile().group
    )

exclude_count =  
    memberships.filter(
        member__officerships__profile=request.user.get_profile()
    ).count()

if exclude_officers_with_profile:
    memberships = memberships.exclude(
        member__officerships__profile=request.user.get_profile()
    )

total_count = memberships.count()
```

which at this point results in:

```
OperationalError at /
(1054, "Unknown column 'U1.id' in 'on clause'")
```

The SQL generated is:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    `membership` 
WHERE (
    `membership`.`group_id` = 2 AND
    `membership`.`level` > 0.0 AND 
    NOT (
        `membership`.`member_id` 
        IN (
            SELECT 
                U2.`member_id` 
            FROM 
                `membership` U0 INNER JOIN `officers` U2 
                ON (U1.`id` = U2.`member_id`) 
            WHERE U2.`profile_id` = 2 
        )
    )
)
```

It appears that the SQL Join's ON statement is referencing an alias that hasn't been defined.  Any ideas why!?  I dropped my MySQL database and re-synced the tables from my models to try and ensure that there weren't any inconsistencies there.

The structure of the models I'm using are:

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, related_name='memberships')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='memberships')
    level = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Officer(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, related_name='officerships')
    profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)

class UserProfile(models.Model)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

class Group(models.Model)
    pass
```

Comment: My django orm isn't really that great so I don't really understand all that is going on, but the error looks quite similar to the one encountered at http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9188

Comment: Yes you're right.  When I implemented the change in the revision linked at the bottom of this closed ticket, the ORM now works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be a symptom of:

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9188

which was fixed as of django revision 9589, I think.  Now how to figure out which revision I'm working from...

---

Confirmed.  When I implemented the change referenced in the ticket above:

http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/9589

my error went away.

Comment: To find your revision, go into ./manage.py shell and do:
>>> import django
>>> django.get_version()
u'1.0-final-SVN-11012'

Comment: When I use the `get_version` function I don't get a revision number, just '1.0-final'...darn.